# Need to extract text out of any binary file using java

Tags: java, parsing

How could I parse content in binary files using java and extract text out of them. I need this to be able to index the content of the binary files using lucene. File types I'm currently supporting are pdf, html, word, excel, ppt, html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/):

> The Apache Tika™ toolkit detects and extracts metadata and text from over a thousand different file types (such as PPT, XLS, and PDF). All of these file types can be parsed through a single interface, making Tika useful for search engine indexing, content analysis, translation, and much more.